# Multiselect using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, multi-select

I am looking for an alternative to normal HTML multiple select with something more user friendly based on jQuery and easier to maintain and implement, any recomendations based on any experience with it would be quite helpful. I need something some thing like [Multiselect](http://loudev.com)

I might have multiple multiSelect drop down's on a single page and the link which I have attached here would fail in that case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My preferred one is chosen

http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Comment: FWIW, this is my preferred one too.

Comment: If you guys can answer this related to chosen multi-select, it will be very helpful. https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/532

Answer (score 2):

You can use

http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect/

or http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Answer (score 2):

- [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/), is another option, seems to be the most robust and feature filled
- [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) as previously mentioned [uses coffeescript and sass]
- [selectize.js](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/) seems to be the quickest setup [uses less styling, you could skip their styling for your own.]

partially sourced from:

- [Is there a properly tested alternative to Select2 or Chosen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544693/is-there-a-properly-tested-alternative-to-select2-or-chosen)
- [What are the differences between Chosen and Select2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575531/what-are-the-differences-between-chosen-and-select2)