# Is there any way to make select, which allows multiple selections look like ordinary?

Tags: html, forms

Is there any way to make select, which allows multiple selections look like ordinary?
Like a drop-down, you know…

```
<select multiple="multiple"></select>
```

look like

```
<select></select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UKf5Y/3/

Comment: Yes, but you need to implement it yourself in JavaScript.

Comment: But the entire point of a drop-down menu is to be able to choose only one item at a time...

Comment: @BoltClock WHAT? What do you think the `multiple` attribute is for then?

Comment: Well … do it without js in a native way was what I want in first place. :)

Design give me only 40px height for this element, so I want get dropdown :( Otherway I must use some js workaround. And I don't like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, no. If there were, how would the user use it to select *multiple* items?

The only way that a multiple selection works is because all of the items are displayed at the same time and they can click-and-drag or click while holding down a modifier key.

If it looked like a drop-down box, how would you navigate to a second item without *deselecting* the first?

Comment: @SilentImp Additionally, how would it display multiple sections when in its standard state? (That way madness lies, etc.)

Comment: It's reasonable to have for example a dropdown with selections that are added to a separate list every time something is chosen from it. The default multiple-select input is pretty unintuitive for most people.

Comment: Agreed, @Juhana. I think they're an awful bit of UI and generally look for alternatives. But I don't think picking items on one control and having your selection show up somewhere else is that much better.

Comment: Yeah, I'd go with autocomplete for a longer list and plain old checkboxes for a shorter list.

Comment: I it not possible — it don't matter how I seeing it … it is how it is :(

Answer (score 0):

The styling of a select list, as well as many different elements in HTML (notably the `input[type='file']` element, is really dependent on the browser. If you're looking to make it visually more appealing / different, you'll really need to use some JavaScript and use an "interface" to your select. Some really nice JavaScript libraries for select lists are **[jQuery Multiselect](http://loudev.com/)**, **[jQuery UI Multiselect](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget)** and **[select2](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2)**, maybe you should look at those.

It's worth noting however that only select2 supports the single/multiple variants, and the styles still **do** look different, but how else would you be able to see multiple selections at one time? You could design your own solution which *did* look identical, but I think more than anything this would be misleading.

Comment: Hmm, I wasn't familiar with select2, but it looks an awful lot like [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/). I wonder if one is a fork of the other?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575531/what-are-the-differences-between-chosen-and-select2 :)