# Is there a properly tested alternative to Select2 or Chosen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, testing, jquery-select2

I am looking for an alternative to Select2 that basically provides the same functionality, but  includes proper tests.

The quest for the holy grail? The last unicorn?

Comment: ideally it would be angularjs based...

Comment: Good question. The answer, of course, is to pony up and write the tests. That's what open source is all about.

Comment: I have started a new project out of this same desire (and some others) recently: https://github.com/arendjr/select3

Answer (score 126, accepted):

[**Selectize.js**](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) is a select2 alternative I've been working on that has a suite of tests using a combination of [testem](https://github.com/airportyh/testem), [syn](https://github.com/bitovi/syn), [mocha](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/), and [chai](http://chaijs.com/). Right now there are the following classes of tests:

- **Interaction**
  Functional tests that makes sure the control behaves as if the user is using it (using [syn](https://github.com/bitovi/syn)).
- **Setup**
  Ensures the control can be initialized properly from existing `<select>` and `<input>` elements.
- **API**
  Tests core API methods for proper functionality.
- **Events**
  Ensures built-in events get fired at the right times with the proper arguments.
- **XSS**
  Tests a handful of potential exploits.

With that said, the tests aren't as expansive as I want them to be, but it's getting there :)

Comment: Thanks for Selectize.js, I found it so much better and easier to use than Chosen or Select2. But please, release it on npm so I can install it and use with browserify without a hassle instead of storing sources in vendor directory.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have been looking around at different select list & tag replacements - not sure why it took this long to find Selectize.

Comment: @andreypopp you can always do this https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/package.json.html#github-urls

Comment: It's nice and pretty, but completely useless when using it with remote data, which is really where select2 shines.

Comment: After wasting 2 days behind Select2, finally went for Selectize.js. And could make it up and running Ajax drop down neatly in few mins. Neat and Clear examples, very good documentation.

Comment: @skerit I found it much easier than select2 even when using with remote data. I belive Select2 is much hyped (sorry, but its my personal opinion, I am not biased towards anyone. Personally I first tried Select2 and then went for Selectize)

Comment: @skerit is right, I have an ajax powered select with selectize and I need to change its value and reset the value. I can't, Is too difficult

Comment: Note: Selectize does NOT support `disabled` states for `<select>` nor `<option>`.

Comment: @Rygu It does support disabled `<select>` elements: https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/examples/basic.html#L83-L98

Comment: I spent 1.5 days with Select2 and it still wasn't good enough. I also tried Selectivity, which didn't do what I needed either. I swapped over to Selectize and had it wrapped up in an hour. Cheers.

Comment: FYI selectize is on npm now so dead easy to integrate if you are using browserify/CommonJS. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/selectize

Comment: If anybody is looking for a alternative to Selectize that doesn't require jQuery as a dependency, I wrote my own plugin: https://github.com/jshjohnson/Choices

Comment: Please also mention **Which is Mobile friendly Select2 or Selectize or Chosen ?**

Comment: Wow, this is very nice and clean after years of Select2 and Chosen! Lovely.

Comment: Addendum, Selectize.js is dead. Go with Choices from @jshjohnson.

Answer (score 4):

**Note:** I'm no longer maintaining this project. Choose another one.

---

[Bselect](http://github.com/gustavohenke/bselect), which I develop, *is* tested, however doesn't include all the features (yet) from Select2/Chosen.

If you want, join me in its development :)

Comment: Maintained fork available at https://github.com/derflocki/bselect

Answer (score 4):

Another possible alternative is [bootstrap-multiselect](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect)

"JQuery multiselect plugin based on Twitter Bootstrap"

Examples and documentation: http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/

- The repository does not contain any automated tests, [manual tests](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/blob/master/tests.html) instead
- Themed using Bootstrap 3
- JavaScript source code is short: 800 lines of code
- 524 stars on GitHub (as of 2013/12/13)

Comment: very nice. doesnt support items with images