# Multiselect dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do you make a combobox with multiselect option? Using Javascript or HTML.  allows you to select multiple options but does not provide a combo/dropdown structure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591311/multi-select-using-jquery

Comment: Look into the following link. Its a multi-select combobox http://asimishaq.com/resources/tools/multi-select-dropdown-list/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not standard HTML functionality. There is either a dropdown, or a multiselect. What you can use, is a library that can handle the conversion, like http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/.

Comment: Yet another option: http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/

Comment: $("#list"+myObject.fields[loop].id).multiselect({
 header: false, 
 height: 150, 
 minWidth: 200,  
 classes: 'ListData',
 checkAllText: 'Check all',
 uncheckAllText: 'Uncheck all',
 selectedText: '# Item Selected',
 noneSelectedText: 'Please Select Item',
 selectedList: 0,
 autoOpen: false,
 multiple: true,
  position: {
   at: 'top'
  }
}); this code displays the dropbox at random position. I need to bind it with the element.

Answer (score -2):

What about this?

```
<select multiple>
  <option value="1">Jan</option>
  <option value="2">Feb</option>
  <option value="3">Mar</option>
  <option value="4">Apr</option>
</select>
```

Comment: That would not create a dropdown